# Using the output of Solve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I had a math problem I solved like this:

```
In[1]:= Solve[2x(a-x)==0, x]
Out[1]= {{x->0}, {x->a}}

In[2]:= Integrate[2x(a-x), {x,0,a}]
Out[2]= (a^3)/3

In[3]:= Solve[(a^3)/3==a, a]
Out[3]= {{a->0}, {a->-Sqrt[3]}, {a->Sqrt[3]}}
```

My question is if I could rewrite this to compute it in one step, rather than having to manually input the result from the previous line. I could easily replace the integral used in step three with the `Integrate` command from step two. But what I can't figure out is how I would use the result from step 1 as the limits of integration in the integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could combine step 1 and 2 by doing something like

```
Integrate[2 x (a - x), {x, ##}] & @@ (x /. Solve[2 x (a - x) == 0, x]);
```

Comment: `Integrate[2 x (a - x), {x, ##}] & @@ (x /. Solve[2 x (a - x) == 0, x])//Solve[#==a,a]&` gets all three steps together.

Comment: @kguler, post it as an answer, alongside an explanation of what it is doing. I'd vote for it.

Comment: @rcollyer, Thank you! I think Heike's answer adresses the specific question asked. What I added is just piping the expression produced by Heike's answer into the pure function `Solve[#==a,a]`. I think some would enjoy to play with the following pure function that combines all three steps: `solveIntegrateSolve := (Integrate[#1, {#2, ## & @@ (#2 /. 
         Solve[#1 == 0, #2])}] // (Solve[# == t, t] & /. t -> #3)) &`. Use it as `solveIntegrateSolve[2x(a-x),x,a]` or `solveIntegrateSolve@@{2x(a-x),x,a}`.

Comment: Nice, ReplaceAll elegantly gets the values out of the result `Solve` produces. Now why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 2):

If you agree to delegate the choice of the (positive oriented) domain to `Integrate`, by means of using `Clip` or `Boole`:

```
In[77]:= Solve[
 Integrate[
   Clip[2 x (a - x), {0, Infinity}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == a, a]

Out[77]= {{a -> 0}, {a -> Sqrt[3]}}
```

or

```
In[81]:= Solve[
 Integrate[
   2 x (a - x) Boole[2 x (a - x) > 0], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 
  a, a]

Out[81]= {{a -> 0}, {a -> Sqrt[3]}}
```

The reason only non-negative roots are found, is that `Integrate` will integrate from the smallest root to the largest root, i.e. from `{x,0,a}` for positive `a` and `{x,a,0}` for negative `a`.